# Query destination account to which a VPC is shared in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ram, resourcemanager

In AWS, I have a centralized networking account that defines all the VPCs and subnets. And each VPC is shared with target accounts using Resource Access Manager (RAM). Given an IP, need to find out the target account ID with which the VPC/subnet has been shared with. Here is what I have done so far:

In the code below, `vpc` parameter contains the vpc lookup response and and `ip_addr` is the IP address we are looking for

```
def lookup_ipaddr (session, ec2_client, vpc, ip_addr):  
  found = False

  if (ipaddress.ip_address(ip_addr) in ipaddress.ip_network(vpc['CidrBlock'])):
    filters = [{'Name':'vpc-id', 'Values':[ vpc['VpcId'] ]}]

    subnets = ec2_client.describe_subnets( Filters = filters )['Subnets']

    for subnet in subnets:
      if (ipaddress.ip_address(ip_addr) in ipaddress.ip_network(subnet['CidrBlock'])):
        found = True

        tags = subnet['Tags']

        # tags returned by previous api is in different form than that required by RAM  
        for tag in tags:
          tag['tagKey'] = tag['Key']
          tag['tagValues'] = [tag['Value']]
          del tag['Key']
          del tag['Value']
 
        print("\n\n")
        print (tags)
        print("\n\n")

        resourceArn = subnet['SubnetArn']
        ram_client = session.client('ram')

        resp = ram_client.get_resource_shares (resourceOwner = 'SELF', tagFilters=tags)
```

However the API call `get_resource_shares` doesn't return any response (except Response Metadata). Any suggestion on how to find out the destination account ID/Principal with which the subnet was shared?

Comment: Perhaps [get_resource_share_associations](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ram.html#RAM.Client.get_resource_share_associations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I was able to obtain the destination account id by using `list_principals` api of AWS Resource Access Manager (RAM): https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ram.html#RAM.Client.list_principals

Here is the full python code:

```
def lookup_ipaddr (session, ec2_client, vpc, ip_addr):  
  found = False

  filters = [{'Name':'vpc-id', 'Values':[ vpc['VpcId'] ]}]

  subnets = ec2_client.describe_subnets( Filters = filters )['Subnets']

  for subnet in subnets:
    if (ipaddress.ip_address(ip_addr) in ipaddress.ip_network(subnet['CidrBlock'])):
      resourceArn = subnet['SubnetArn']
      ram_client = session.client('ram')

      resp = ram_client.list_principals(
        resourceOwner = 'SELF',
        resourceArn = resourceArn
      )

      print(f"Subnet {subnet['SubnetId']} is shared with account [{resp['principals'][0]['id']}]")
      found = True
      break
  return found
```